# using idioms in vim for perl

Tags: perl, vim, idioms

I have the perl-support plugin enabled. now, I tried the `\idd` idiom shortcut which would  give you a `my ($,$);` statement with the cursor placed on the first var.  Now the second var is displayed as `<+name+>`. In effect the `my` line after entering the first variables name would be

```
my ( $top, $<+name+> );
```

If it was a code snippet I could have easily used tab to go to the next field, but it is not working in this case. How do I quickly move to changing the 2nd part of the idiom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are *jump targets*, and you can visit them with <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd>. See [perlsupport-templates-jump](http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-doc/perlsupport.html#perlsupport-templates-jump) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If this is VIM, why don't you just use VIM's navigation keys for this?

<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> (that is a capital W) will move you three words to the left, right onto `$<+name+>`.

You could also try:

<kbd>f</kbd><kbd><</kbd> to put the cursor on the `<`, and then you can change `<+name+>`.

Comment: yes, that is always possible . What made me ask the question is the special way in which the variable is displayed . for snippets , the tab actually lets u change  jus that particular word (without you having to delete any of the characters like '<' or '{'.).

Comment: if we had to manually move and then change it , using the idiom wouldnt be of much help . typing by hand would do better mostly